# Story Planning Software

Tags: software, planning, story

Because of the size of the task, I find it hard to start planning a story. I think that software for planning stories would help me, but I couldn't find any free software for this purpose. I need one that will show me everything I need to plan, one that will make it easy for me to plan it.

Do you know of any software like this?

Comment: In conjunction with software, you might also like to consider following a step-by-step planning process like the Snowflake method. https://www.advancedfictionwriting.com/articles/snowflake-method/

Comment: *I think that software for planning stories would help me* I don't think it would.  I think it would (a) present you the problem of learning to use the software (which may in the long run be worth it) but (b) once you have mastered the software your problems with planning stories have become more complicated, now you have to use the software to plan your stories.  First figure out a solution to your creative problem, then find software to support your future endeavours.

Comment: There is anything from Scrivener or Wiki software to Dramatica. The first two will allow you to save information in a nice way. The last one will also hit you over the head with their Method. Do you have any idea of how free or restrained you want the planning to be? Do you also want a method included in the planning?

Comment: Is there any reason you [posted this initially](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/63602/23927), deleted it after half-an-hour, and then reposted it again?

Comment: That was about a year ago, and I forgot I even posted this question.

Answer (score 2):

I use [yWriter](http://www.spacejock.com/yWriter.html). It's free to use, no ads, no licence fee etc., but you can register it to show support to the author of the software and receive updates about new versions.

It doesn't have the bells and whistles of commercial software, but helps with planning and keeping track of characters, locations, chapters, word counts, etc.

It won't actually show you what you need to plan (that's down to you as the author) and it assumes you know how to write, but allows you to make notes on each location, important items, organise scenes in your chapters, shuffle the order of chapters, scenes and so on, write scenes specifying whose viewpoint it's related by on a scene by scene basis. I like it because it allows me to keep notes on all the various aspects of my writing in one place.

It looks a little daunting when you first open it, and writing notes on your characters, locations, important items etc. is a little time-consuming at first, but well worth doing. It's also completely optional with this software - you don't need to write notes on everything before starting to plan your scenes and chapters. I've used software previously that made you plan everything to the nth degree before you could get going. yWriter's very flexible though and well worth a look.